# How to create array from json data in shell script

Tags: arrays, shell

I used to read the json file using

```
recordtype=python -c 'import sys,json,ast;print ast.literal_eval(json.dumps(json.load(sys.stdin)["record"].keys())) < 1.json
```

I got the value of recordtype like

```
['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

In order for me to loop to the recordtype, I need the array like this

```
(1 2 3 4)
```

How to convert the above to this type of array? And if its possible to loop through the above value? I used

```
for type in "${recordtype[@]}"
```

The json would be:

```
{"modes":["a","b","c"],"recordtype":{"1":{"mode":"a","inputpath":"/us/","archive":""},"2":{"mode":"b","inputpath":"","archive":""}}}
```

Comment: Could we get the file `1.json` type sample data, please.

Comment: {
  "modes": [
    "a",
    "b",
    "c"
  ],
  "recordtype": {
    "1": {
      "mode":"a",
      "inputpath":"/us/",
      "archive":""
    },
    "2": {
      "mode":"b",
      "inputpath":"",
      "archive":""
    }
  }
}

Comment: Please, add it to the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about running though the generated string again?

```
arr=($(echo "['1', '2', '3', '4']" | grep -oP "'[^']*'" | awk '{print substr($0, 2, length($0) - 2)}'))
```

This extracts everything between single quotes, then strips the quotes on the sides, and gives what you want.

```
ibug@linux:~ $ echo "${arr[@]}"
1 2 3 4
ibug@linux:~ $ for i in "${arr[@]}"; do echo "$i"; done
1
2
3
4
ibug@linux:~ $
```

Comment: yeah thanks its working. But the issue it can't be static. The array is dynamic. And can you explain me the print part after awk?

Comment: @SRIRAMRAMACHANDRAN The array ***is*** dynamic. Just replace the first part `echo "[...]"` with your actual output.

Comment: @SRIRAMRAMACHANDRAN The print part is an AWK program that removes the first and the last character from each line, which is the unwanted single quotes.

Comment: thanks for the explanation... and what does substr doing?

Comment: @SRIRAMRAMACHANDRAN It's the core part that does the quote-stripping job. It takes the substring starting from position 2, with a length of `length - 2`, which should be the part of the string exactly without the quotes.